# Should a diamond moderator having voted to close a question, delete counterarguments from that question's comments?

Tags: discussion, comment, closing

Like many people with an interest in mathematics right now, I want to get a deeper understanding where Atiyah's proof of Riemann Hypothesis might fall down.  I searched and found no such question here so I [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934132).

Coming from a Fields medal winner this claimed proof cannot be assumed to sit in the same category as the many cranky proofs.

MathOverflow has a policy to not permit discussion of conjectured proofs of open problems, and that policy was quoted as a closure reason.  There were both close and reopen votes and there was some debate in the comments defending the question's validity on the grounds:

- MSE is fundamentally a place people come to get mathematics questions answered, and
- this is actually a hot mathematics question right now which a lot of people want answers to,
- unlike MO, MSE has no such policy, and
- what really is gained by preventing people from coming here to get their questions answered?
- If the question is closed and deleted, others wanting to learn will simply come and ask the same.

A moderator who voted to re-close the question then deleted the counterargument to the close votes but left in place the pro-close arguments, claiming that the comments are not the place to discuss whether closure is valid.  I think the comments are precisely the right place to place a counterargument the question's closure - where others who might cast a vote can consider them.  This left a really sour taste in my mouth and I felt it was undemocratic.  Is it just me?

Comment: I would be in favor of closing questions like that with a link to [this post on MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/3902/5442) which explains why the question would be closed there.  I have always thought that we had the same policy as MO to avoid posts about preprints that claim to prove famous conjectures. The fact that a question is "hot" that "many people want answers to" is not really an argument in favor of including the question.

Comment: At the same time, although some frustration about the seeming silence about the proof is understandable, sources such as [this](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2018/09/skepticism-surrounds-renowned-mathematician-s-attempted-proof-160-year-old-hypothesis) make it more clear what is going on.

Comment: @CarlMummert On the other hand, that article has the most "authoritative" part of it be a quote from an economist who has "studied" the Riemann hypothesis. While I largely agree with the statement made by that person, neither he nor I are really experts in this area.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: they did interview John Baez, as well.

Comment: @CarlMummert Ahh, good point. I had missed that part.

Comment: I think the aspect that is frustrating for some people is that they want to see a bunch of experts talk about the proof, while the actual situation seems to be that few experts want to say anything about it, which leaves a kind of vacuum. I have no inside information but a little searching made the situation seem clear enough.

Comment: @CarlMummert I think MSE users come here to get at least one level deeper understanding than that article gives, and the silence is a disservice to, and causes embarrassment to Atiyah. To require a question to address some specific aspect of the preprint, excludes interested parties from understanding and learning, because I could ask "why is relying upon a flow of weights in a *finite* Von Neumann algebra" risky, then I would simply get a handful of upvotes and an answer which teaches me nothing because it is beyond me.

Comment: ...but the question I ask here is really about whether the democratic process of closure and reopening is being distorted rather than the suitability of the question itself.

Comment: It's not that mse has, or should have, the same policies as mo; it's that the reasons for drastically limiting the discussion on mo also apply here. Those reasons have been explained on mo, and I urge anyone who wants to know why discussion should be restricted here to search out the discussions there.

Comment: As for democracy, democratic societies elect leaders for a reason.

Comment: @GerryMyerson and hold them to account for reasons too

Comment: Why is this off-topic? It's a question about moderation policy. Once again, a close vote is not a super-disagree vote.

Comment: @T.Bongers  I don't close vote on meta in lieu of a "super-disagree vote".  Please don't harass dedicated users on this site, both on main and on meta, who find good reason to close a post as off topic, not because they "super-disagree" with it, but for one of many other good reasons.  Usually I appreciate your input; but here I think you're under the influence of the asker's "conspiracy theory" shenanigans.

Comment: @T.Bongers: Note that one of the question types [*explicitly* called out as off topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) is `your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”` The post itself is somewhat all over the place; briefly touching a number of different issues, throwing out accusations, and an entirely different question appearing in the title. I did not vote to close/delete, but *I can very certainly understand them*.

Comment: ... It would be better, I think, if the OP would pick a specific topic to talk about, and make a post *on that topic* without digressing into everything else and without making it a place to vent ill-feelings.

Comment: @amWhy I don't agree with the asker's premise either, and downvoted the post. But I don't see any reason to remove this from meta. I also appreciate a lot of your input and it's unfortunate that you view my comment as "harass[ment of] dedicated users," which mentioned no particular user and pinged no one. Perhaps that's more telling of your actions than mine.

Comment: I have voted undelete on this question not because I think there is any issue with the moderator(s) actions, but because I think the broader issue of "why don't we host questions on this proof of the Riemann Hypothesis" should have a question on meta, and because the discussion was headed back to the main question now that this one was deleted.

Comment: @CarlMummert should "show be" be "should be""?::  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934132/where-if-anywhere-might-atiyahs-proof-of-the-riemann-hypothesis-break-down?noredirect=1#comment6065160_2934132

Comment: @CarlMummert: Great, except we still don't have a question on meta about the issue of "why don't we host questions on this proof of the Riemann Hypothesis". If people are interested in that issue, then someone should make a post about it, rather than undeleting a post that isn't about that issue and has a lot of problems besides.

Comment: ... and even if we were to consider this post as having many topics including that issue, I don't see how one can expect to have a fair discussion about that *specific* issue when when it would be so inexorably tied to all of the other issues present in this post if discussed here.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Maybe a better way to put that previous comment is that, if discussion on the policy question were to happen *here in this post*, you exclude everyone unwilling to hijack a meta thread from participating in that discussion, and you exclude everyone who doesn't follow highly downvoted complaints of moderator abuse from *even being aware* of discussion.

Comment: @Hurkyl I don't concur "moderator abuse" is a fitting term for the claim. Really this question claims heavy handedness, and asks whether moderators should avoid stepping in to decide a well-working democratic process one way, when there are numerous votes on both sides. Nevertheless your point stands.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, moderators should remove meta-comments from the main site. The suitability of a question for the site should be discussed on meta.

Comment: I agree meta comments in general should eventually be removed, but in the first few minutes while close and reopen votes are being cast, is it really that urgent a matter that a moderator should vote and remove one side of the argument from the comments?

Comment: @RobertFrost: You keep saying "remove *one side*", as if there is another side of discussion appearing in comments that is allowed to stand.

Comment: @Hurkyl pretty sure that was removed later after I raised the one-sidedness as an issue but I cannot confirm that now.

Comment: @Robert: I can post the deleted comments here if you want, including deletion times. There was no one-sidedness. I only left the comments of Prezmo as it was pertaining to your question, and of Arnuad which pointed towards previous meta discussions (so when someone *does* come to meta to discuss meta issues, there is a reference to the past discussions for them to use). Let me also say that part of my decision to delete the comments was because several of them generated flags as unfriendly and unkind.

Comment: @AsafKaragila several of them generating flags sounds implausible.  My one unkind comment (thoroughly deserved) came only after you deleted my comments as a point-scoring exercise and accompanied by a sarcastic comment which was mildly funny to be fair.

Comment: @Robert: You seem to be calling me a liar in a way that, how did *you* put it? "basically the same effect, with the added strength of giving you deniability."

Comment: @AsafKaragila except in this case my motivation is that I can't see any of the history in order to check the facts while you hold all the aces by virtue of being a moderator and I feel like my status is being manipulated downwards by a person in a position of power and I've never had a problem before with how any other mod has wielded the diamond.

Comment: @Robert: What motivation I have for this, really? I could have deleted your question, I could have suspended you after that comment of yours, and every time I am giving you seemingly undeserved leeway.

Comment: @AsafKaragila at first I thought, you know what, kudos to Asaf not giving me a penalty for my unkind comment but in the back of my mind there was feeling... or on the other hand maybe that's just been put in the kit bag to hold over me for later. And now here we are, sure enough it's come out with the threat of revealing my comment.  Really, it was wrong of you to grant me undeserved leeway and now hold it against me, you should have given the penalty and let that be the end of it. Some people enjoy the feeling of being in a position of power over others & this is exactly what's going on here.

Comment: @Robert: So first you call me names, then you call me a liar. What would be next? Call me a ruthless incompetent dictator? If you're escalating, why are you surprised that at some point I might have enough? Seriously. Stop for a minute. Step back. Think it through. Yelling "HELP HELP I'M BEING REPRESSED" helps nobody...

Comment: @Robert: Oh, wait. You already called me a dictator by claiming that I only deleted the comments that supported your question being reopened. How silly of me to forget. It's right there, on the top part of my screen...

Comment: "several of them generating flags sounds implausible." @Robert, I think you owe Asaf an apology.

Comment: @GerryMyerson why's that?

Comment: I didn't think I'd need to spell it out for you, Robert, but here goes. Asaf wrote, "Let me also say that part of my decision to delete the comments was because several of them generated flags as unfriendly and unkind." When you write, "several of them generating flags sounds implausible," you are suggesting Asaf is a liar, and that's way over the line. Please, Robert, if your reputation here means anything to you, apologize.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm at the disadvantage of no longer being able to see the comment thread and this leaves me to rely upon my (pretty unreliable) memory.  I have no problem putting my hands up and saying "you know what, I shouldn't have called you that name" but I genuinely have no recollection of saying anything other than one comment which would have generated any flag.  Since you think it a matter of integrity and reputation I think the only course of action is to take up Asaf's offer fo reinstating the comments and times and I will be more than willing to apologise accordingly.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In light of Gerry's comment can I please take you up on your offer and ask you to reinstate the comments including deletion times and all flags so I can see the facts and apologise accordingly?  Thanks

Comment: @GerryMyerson it appears (on the basis of limited evidence) only one comment of mine was flagged, and that was this: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46967428#46967428 on what I considered a well-natured handful of comments exchanged about the acceptability of the question. So I'm comfortable with my surprise that the post generated "several" flags and I'm satisfied everybody commenting on the post, myself included acted in a friendly manner and with integrity. Judge as you see fit.

Comment: @Robert: I'm sorry I didn't want to deal with it over the weekend. I am expecting a long train ride, and I will deal with this then. Let me point out, in advance, some information will be omitted (e.g. the names of users, etc.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila no need for an apology, you do this for nothing. I'll apologise anyway. Im sorry if "sounds implausible" was unfair. It did sound implausible but I now realise apparently friendly comments were flagged and also comments of other people.

Comment: @Robert: There was a comment openly calling the norms of this site "crap" and telling people they should be "ashamed" and that only SE gets to dictate rules. All those things in full caps. Do you see why something like that would get flagged? And why people would take it as offensive? (That particular comment was flagged, but then also self-deleted. Even the user who posted it felt it was too much.)

Comment: @Robert: As a whole, I think that you are way too sensitive after the elections, where there was some focus on 'cranks', and you and others felt jeopardized. **I am not your enemy**. I hoped that you'd extend any trust you had in other moderators to me (and Aloizio). Regardless to our previous interactions (which I hope weren't too awful). Openly calling me a liar, and claiming you never had problems "with other moderators", however, that's pretty much the opposite.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I voted for you but I was oversensitive. Only because I believe I was right about the question and I thought democracy would bear that out. And sure enough the questions about the proof kept coming. I didn't feel jeopardised by the elections. My opinions about the elections weren't about me. I believe MSE is a place where people should come to get questions answered first and foremost, and for me, accumulating a catalogue of q&A's which will be useful in the future is only a goal insofar as it supports that. So longstanding value of the questions should be secondary imh.

Answer (score 9):

Your question should have been closed; there is something like a policy:

[Proof Verification of Open Problems](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19652/proof-verification-of-open-problems)

The point is questions like this fall into at least one of two categories:

- The questions is too broad.
- The paper is not worth the consideration.

You can pick which one you prefer to assume in this case.

On the removal of comments, just to repeat another answer, meta comments do not belong on the main site.

Comment: I like this answer because it's more or less the comment left on the question which led to the two or three comments, which initially led to the question being retained / reopened (I can't see the history, nor can I see the comments but I guess we just have to repeat the process here).  My response was something like...

Comment: ...most proofs of famous conjectures are wrong, even those by leading mathematicians. Andrew Wiles' first proof of Fermat's last theorem is a prime example. While MO has an explicit and strict policy to disallow these, MSE's policy to close questions about such proofs has been established entirely in the context of discussing proofs which did not come from a Field's medal winner.  Given that this claimed proof originates where it does, it's a MATHS QUESTION and probably the most compelling one around right now....

Comment: ...and given that this site is fundamentally and above all other things, a place where people come to get maths questions answered, this should be a place where people can come to get this question answered. Now I wasn't at the time of asking aware of various related sensitivities, but as it happens in my opinion for everybody to treat these as the emperor's new clothes and look at each other shiftily and say nothing, is actually insensistive, and it's misguided. I strongly believe the most respectful treatment of the proof is to discuss its mathematical merit openly.

Comment: Incidentally, it seems to me that your linked meta question holds up the "this question is permitted" argument more than it does the "question should be closed".  The linked meta question suggests short proofs which can be quickly assessed will result in answers which are meritous for the site. Sir Michael Atiyah's proof is actually very compact because it stays at quite a high level.  There is next to no effort required for a MSE user, having considered the clained proof to digest the question, and the answer will actually be quite revealing for most users.

Comment: The answer, I believe, is that the merit of the proof will depend upon whether the Todd function is well-defined.  From what I can discern, it appears that if it is a complex analytic function then one can quickly deduce the function cannot have the properties claimed, and the proof quickly reduces to the Todd function being zero everywhere.  But there is perhaps doubt as to whether the function is indeed complex analytic.  There is also further doubt as to whether it is fundamentally ill-defined as related work yields a fine structure constant which differs from the known value.

Comment: An accurate assessment is beyond me but I have no doubt it would be of interest to users, and I am also resolute that it would be the most respectful thing to Sir Atiyah for the site to afford him the dignity of hosting it. For me there's absolutely no shame in reaching for the stars, soaring higher than most of us ever dream, and falling flat on ones face every now and then.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the situation. To me it was a virtual certainty   once I heard the news that it's wrong and likely so in a non relevant way. You say " it's a MATHS QUESTION and probably the most compelling one around right now and probably the most compelling one around right now" Not at all. It's pretty much irrelevant. Move on.

Comment: I expected a comment like this (that doesn't mean I'm critical of it). Yours is an expert's position and I wouldn't dispute it on a site frequented by experts. Some are heard muttering "not even wrong" but the reality for many of us (the non-experts), which I think you fail to appreciate is that even if fundamentally flawed, the conjectured proof almost certainly contains insightful fragments of genius which we'd like to understand better. Perhaps it is hard work to give an exposition of them.  It would indeed be sad if there were none.

Comment: @RobertFrost It's in  a way pretty funny how you bring up the emperor's new cloth etc for others and then are all keen on this paper. Why exactly? Did you already read a book on analytic number theory? If not, then maybe do that. There are great ideas in there that actually work. If yes, then maybe read a more advanced one. If you did that too. Then  there are many interesting papers out there to study that are actually correct and relevant. Or maybe read one of those papers of Atiyah for which he got the Fields medal.

Comment: Why do I take interest in this paper? Because a man who raised the ceiling of human understanding before claimed to have done so again and that idea sparked something in my imagination.  Did I read a book on analytic number theory? No, I never even knew what it was until I Googled it after your comment and would never have had a reason to do so before. Maybe it would be better if mathematicians of my level stuck to reading about it in the newspaper.

Answer (score 4):

As you've come to Meta to argue the merits of asking a Question on the main site, let's leave aside the issue of whether similar argument through Comments on the Question should be removed, though I hope in the future you will appreciate the virtue of having a polite discussion here as opposed to a heated discussion there.  Entertain instead a discussion about [allowed-questions](/questions/tagged/allowed-questions) for this particular Question.

Yes, I too am curious about what substance there is to Atiyah's proposed approach to proving the Riemann Hypothesis.  It would be great if there were a source I could turn to for a more incisive presentation than what I've seen in the media (see [Phys.org](https://phys.org/news/2018-09-math-greatest-mysteries-riemann-hypothesis.html), [New Scientist](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2180504-riemann-hypothesis-likely-remains-unsolved-despite-claimed-proof/), and [Gizmodo](https://gizmodo.com/mathematicians-skeptical-of-supposed-million-dollar-pro-1829301425), among others that present some amount of skeptical assessment).

But the mission of Math.SE is limited as to the size of a reply that can be conjured and the scope of material that can be given a fairly dispositive Answer.  We should presumably await at least a preprint of the proposed proof.  When Atiyah posted [a different unsolved problem claim](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09366) to arXiv.org in 2016, it became possible for [various MathOverflow threads](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288180/atiyahs-paper-non-existent-complex-6-sphere) to provide analysis.

Connecting the Riemann Hypothesis to the determination of the fine-structure constant of theoretical physics sounds to me like a topic that few experts will be able to evaluate in the early days of such a preprint, so I'm resigned to being patient.  All the more reason to avoid accusations of bad motives in the meantime.

Comment: Some hints as to the problems exist - I saw a claim that a theorem he relies upon to define the fine structure constant, when evaluated computationally yields a totally different number to the constant. Then there are a few very technical comments in a MO post hinting at a) the composite Todd function is not well-defined, and b) it is just a constant function. Then there seem to be other suggestions (as per John Baez's comment) that really to join the dots there is a vast amount of detail and work missing...

Comment: ...So on the face of it, people seem to be jumping pretty quickly to the conclusion that it's quite a naive attempt, albeit subject to seeing the full detail. But I don't see any issue with people coming out and stating that as a tentative initial assessment on here as an answer to a question.

Comment: I don't think "naive" is the right word.  People often make very subtle mistakes in mathematics, ones that require sophistication.  I think Math.SE eschews providing mere conjecture about "a vast amount of detail and work missing", though that may turn out in perspective to be true of Atiyah's remarks.

Comment: When I suggest naive I refer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311280/what-is-the-definition-of-the-function-t-used-in-atiyahs-attempted-proof-of-the#comment776260_311280 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311280/what-is-the-definition-of-the-function-t-used-in-atiyahs-attempted-proof-of-the#comment776266_311280 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311280/what-is-the-definition-of-the-function-t-used-in-atiyahs-attempted-proof-of-the#comment776351_311280 so only naive in a *relative* sense

Comment: I edited your title to be more focused on the allowed-questions issue and to remove in part the tone of accusation.  I think further editing on your part of the body of the Question might result in reopening the Question on that basis, if it interests you.

Comment: I was never asking about whether the question was on topic. There were maybe 7 upvotes and 5 downvotes on the original question, and as many reopen votes as close votes. A closer had kindly given their reasons and I gave my counterargument, which I still believe to be a legitimate use of the comments. The question was probably destined to stay and be answered. Then a diamond mod came along, deleted my counterargument and decided the matter. This meta question asks  whether it's legitimate use of the diamond to decide a matter against the democratic will of the users.

Comment: Okay, rolled back. You are the expert on what you want to ask here.  Accusing the moderators of abusing you is not the way I'd approach this.   Voting is not indicative of whether an off-topic Question is "destined to stay and be answered."